# Is there any performance difference between conditional classes, CSS-in-JS, CSS Modules and utility-first CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, tailwind-css, css-in-js

Is there any difference (specially performance-related) between dynamic/conditional classes (like [JedWatson's classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)) with SCSS, CSS Modules, CSS-in-JS (styled-components, JSS, Emotion, etc) and utility-first CSS (Tailwind)?

I'm kick-starting a new React (probably with Next) project in a few weeks and I'm currently doing my researches to build the front-end tech stack. Any help and any opinion are appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: When it comes to CSS performance you only really have to worry about animations. Your code has to be *really* bad to cause bottleneck

Comment: Mobile devices especially the average android devices are known to have performance issues running JS, so I would study my users device usage before choosing to use css in js. More and more users are surfing the web with mobile devices now.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not something I'd focus on when choosing how to write CSS. Most of the time, you probably won't need to worry about the performance of your CSS, though there are a few exceptions:

- Animations: animations can slow things down considerable, especially on low-powered devices. However, the potential bottlenecks here are identical for all ways of writing CSS
- CSS bundle size: the smaller, the better. Though realistically this isn't too important until your shipping 20+ KB of CSS gzipped, and even then it only really affects the slowest internet connections. For large pages, almost nothing beats a utility approach like TailwindCSS. For smaller pages/sites, everything's going to be small enough that it won't really matter.
- Selector complexity. If selectors have the potential to match many elements (e.g., the owl `* + *`), then that can impact runtime performance as the DOM grows. This never happens with utility-first CSS, and probably doesn't happen with CSS Modules or CSS-in-JS.

Instead of performance, I'd recommend looking at the developer experience for each of the CSS "frameworks" and how it relates to the rest of your tech-stack. 99 / 100 times (citation needed), your performance bottleneck will not be your CSS.